# Any way to change order failed feature methods appear in build/tests/classes/MyTestScript.html

Tags: spock, geb

In Spock/Geb when a feature method fails, a stack trace for that feature method is added to MyTestScript.html under the "Failed Tab". (Where "MyTestScript" is the name of your geb test script.)

If there are failures for multiple feature methods, each feature method with its stack trace is printed out in alphabetical order. I was wondering if there was a way to have the feature methods listed in execution order instead.

I read the book of GEB section 7.2.9 to 7.2.12 and didn't see it mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible due to the idea that every test should be ran independently. If you are having troubles with readability maybe your best bet would be to reorganize your specs and definitions.

Comment: Yeah I know about the whole run independently thing, but I figured if you are using the stepwise spock annotation, that it should print out in the defined order since stepwise denotes that you want to run your feature methods in a particular order and they are dependent on the previous one passing.